# Redis expire keys

Tags: java, redis, jedis, leaderboard, sortedset

I've some leaderboard stats for my players. Leaderboards have daily,weekly and monthly stats. So I using redis with its expire feature for leaderboards but there's a thing that I'd want to know. Is there any method that make key expired but if the key has expire already, it will not touch it. If the method doesn't exist, what is the more performance friendly method to check and set it? I've a lot of keys to check and set I don't want to slow the process.

**Code**

```
try (Jedis resource = redisManager.getResource()) {
    Pipeline pipeline = resource.pipelined();
    pipeline.multi();

    for (PlayerData playerData : playerDataList) {
        if (playerData.getKill() > 0) {
            pipeline.zincrby("game.kill.total", playerData.getKill(), playerData.getId());
            pipeline.zincrby("game.kill.monthly", playerData.getKill(), playerData.getId());
            pipeline.zincrby("game.kill.weekly", playerData.getKill(), playerData.getId());
        }
    }

    //if the key doesn't have expire date, add expire date to key.

    pipeline.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you key in the Redis is expired, Redis will handle it internally, by deleting them periodically. check [official document](https://redis.io/commands/expire)

Redis `exist` API can help to check if the key exists. [doc](https://redis.io/commands/exists) In Java [Spring RedisTemplate hasKey API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html#hasKey-K-) can help.

Best practice to handle Redis key is

1. check key exists, if is maybe expire it or use it
2. set key values
3. set expire time. Always set the expiration, otherwise, your Redis may run out of memory soon.

If you're using Redis in multithread, it's another story. You have to use Redis Lock.

Comment: What about checking if the key exist or not in pipeline then add datas into key in another pipeline? May using 2 pipeline same time causing problem?

Comment: yes, you can only use one pipeline at the same time. Redis is the single-core thread itself. There is no way you can use multiple pipelines at the same time.

Comment: I'd want to solve this problem without using Redis Lock. I've an idea about it and I'd like to know what you think about the idea. So basically I'll run redis commands in async(FutureTask) and using default jedis not a pipeline. It will check 10 key if key exist or not and if the key is exist it add expire time to key.

Another idea is check the keys from starting of the game and add the players data end of the game.

Comment: If your action (set the expiration time) is stateless, just do it because Redis is single-core, will not affect the results.

Comment: I wish redis has command that expire key if the key doesn't have any expire date not refresh it...

Comment: you can use `ttl` to check how many expiration time the key left, if return -1 means the key doesn't have expiration time then you can delete it or set the expiration time.

Comment: Well that's the problem. I've to check a lot of keys as you can see from the example but there's no way to solve it without this method. I'm going to check keys and set.

Comment: If so, consider using Lua script instead of the java program.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have records that have no expire date set on them?